# Where does rails hide js & css from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm using `gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'`  and I am trying to fine tune the innate JS it is using. Where is it hiding in my app?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with this js? Why not include js files from this plugin in your project by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gem which jquery-fileupload-rails
```

locate the gem path

Comment: "I'm on a highway to hell..."

Comment: You should never edit gem source code like that, this local change won't be ever deployed to production. You may fork the gem and put your patches instead.